# Ignore json files that do not have the required key

Tags: python, json

I have json files with mostly the same architecture from which I would like to extract "text" values. But in this folder some of the files do not have this key, so I would like to ignore them.

This is what a json file with missing values looks like:

```
{
    "question": {
        "id": "S6565706",
        "identifier": {
            "number": "745678",
        
        },
        "textsAnswer": null,
        "closure": null,
        "reporting": null,
        "review": null
    }
}
```

Here is what a file looks like with the keys present:

```
{
    "question": {
        "id": "S6565706",
        "identifier": {
            "number": "745678",

        },
        "textsAnswer": {
            "textAnswer": {
                "INF": {
                    "type": "JV",
                },
                "text": "xxxxxxxx"
            }
        },
        "closure": {
            "codeClosure": "PUB",
            "wordedClosure": "TYPE1",
            "INF": {
                "typeINF": "JV",
            }
        },
        "reporting": null,
        "review": null
    }
}
```

My goal is to keep the text part, which initially worked on files with no null values.

```
dic= []
for filename in os.listdir(rootdir):
    with open(rootdir+filename, encoding='utf-8') as json_file: 
        data = json.load(json_file) 
        jsonData = data['question']['textsAnswer']['textAnswer']

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the rest of the code :

```
    for item in jsonData:
        if item == 'text':
            dic.append(jsonData['text'])
```

Comment: You can't get that error for a missing key. I would expect KeyError. Your json might be: `{"key1":null}`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the key exists, depending on the file it is sometimes empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your `json` *did* in fact have `null` items sometimes. You can check for that like this:

```py
dic= []
for filename in os.listdir(rootdir):
    with open(rootdir+filename, encoding='utf-8') as json_file: 
        data = json.load(json_file) 
        d = data['question']['textsAnswer']
        if d:
            jsonData = d['textAnswer']
            if 'text' in jsonData:
                dic.append(jsonData['text'])
```

**Update:** updated with new key names

Comment: Thank you so much. I still get an error on key 2 even though it still exists, although null

Comment: It works for me. Once I had corrected the syntax in your json, both snippets work and my code collects nothing when there is a `null`, or the contents of the `"text"` key.

Comment: KeyError : "key2"

Comment: Please update your question with your **actual** json.

Comment: Please upvote any answers that have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a key is in a dict with the `in` keyword.

Use that as a check that the key exists before trying to to access it.

```py
    json_dict = {"key1" : [], "key2" : [], "key3" : []}
    
    if "key1" in json_dict:
        print("key exists")
        json_dict["key1"].append("some value")
    
    if "key4" in json_dict:
        print("will never reach this line")
```